# Proof-verfication: $f\in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}))$ and $f^{(n)}(0)=0$

Tags: real-analysis, functions, derivatives, continuity

> Proof-verfication: $f\in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}))$ with $f^{(n)}(0)=0$.

We have $$f: \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}, \, x\mapsto f(x)=\begin{cases}e^{-\frac{1}{x^2}} \, \text{ for } x\neq 0, \\ 0 \quad \quad  \text{for } x=0\end{cases}$$

After having derived $f$ a few times, one can conclude that for all $x\neq 0$ and $n\in \mathbb{N} : f(x)=e^{-\frac{1}{x^2}} \implies f^{(n)}(x)=\frac{p_{n-1}}{x^{3n}}\cdot e^{-\frac{1}{x^2}}$ with $p_{n-1}$ being a polynomial of $n-1$-degree. I proved it by induction. But how can I prove that $f^{(n)}(0)=0$?

Answer (score 1):

The polynomial is bounded in every neighborhood of $0,$ so you can ignore it. You're left contemplating $\dfrac{e^{-1/x^2}}{x^{3n}}$ as $x\to 0.$ Let's experiment: Suppose $n$ is fixed and $x=1/k, k= 1,2,\dots.$ How does $k^{3n}e^{-k^2}$ behave as $k\to \infty?$

Comment: Well, as $k\to \infty$, we have $k^{3n}e^{-k^2} \to 0$.